# Recordset findfirst operation not supported

Tags: c#, dao

I can get a table open in a recordset. But trying to check for an existing record with FindFirst throws "Operation is not supported for this type of object." And I can't find a way to refine a Recordset via SELECT or SQL.

When working in the IDE, FindFirst is offered when working with DAO.Recordset variables so it must be part of the object.

I recognize by how hard it is to find information that this is not a popular area. But it is supported and I assume that is because at least some are still utilizing it. For the near term, simply being able to check for existing records in a DB will go a long ways for me.

But I would further appreciate any help cracking open the door to C# DAO documentation, references or any other knowledge. (MS site only references VB.) I'm having no luck finding the right search terms.

Here's the code I'm trying to get working...

```
DAO.DBEngineClass DbEng = new DAO.DBEngineClass();
Db = DbEng.OpenDatabase(txtDB.Text, null, null, null);
Rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Data", DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenTable, null, DAO.LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic);
Rs.FindFirst(@"Full_Path Like '\\DELL-2\Tosh-2TB-1\tib\B1_bad.tib'")
```

Comment: I'd also _strongly_ suggest looking into newer alternatives. As a hobbyist programmer, it is well worth your time to stick with more common technologies - it will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in MS docs:

> In a Microsoft Access workspace, if you don't specify a type, DAO attempts to create the type of Recordset with the most functionality available, **starting with table**

So rather than "loosely" opening a Recordset with a SELECT statement as I had almost always done in VBA, I opened it typed for "the most functionality available" - DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenTable. VBA does helpful things "in the dark". In order to increase "functionality" and get the FindFirst function to work, I had to open it with the "less functional" DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset. I didn't find anything to confirm it, but I am assuming that when I provided no optional parameters in my Open statement, VB did the work in the background of intuiting Dynaset.

I discovered the solution only because, in seeing all of MS docs around DAO deal only with VB, I had started to abandon my hope of moving away from VB and started porting my project back to it. In following a different path into different docs, I came across this:

> With dynaset- and snapshot-type Recordset objects in a Microsoft Access workspace, you can also use the Find methods, such as FindFirst, to locate a specific record based on criteria. If the record isn't found, the NoMatch property is set to True. **For table-type Recordset objects, you can scan records using the Seek method.**

also failing to state that with table-type, **you can ONLY use Seek.**

I read that paragraph, especially in light of the other statement of table-type being the "most functional", that this was referring to **additional** not **exclusive** functionality.